# Add together the bytes of a string

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA in Excel. I have a five character alphanumeric string and I want to add the bytes together to get a total.

```
Dim strMyString As String
strMyString = “ab9cd”
```

How do I convert the string to bytes, then add each byte together? I think I need to convert each character of the string to bytes in hexadecimal, then convert each hexadecimal byte to decimal.  Then I could add them together.  Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: No need to convert each character. VBA offer two ways to directly convert the string in an array. Please, see my answer and send some feedback.

Comment: Nice.  Got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try using/understanding the next code:

```
Sub playWithBytes()
   Dim strMyString As String, arrB() As Byte
   strMyString = "ab9cd"
   arrB() = StrConv(strMyString, vbFromUnicode) 'create a byte array from the string
   Debug.Print UBound(arrB())  'it returns 4 (5 elements in a zero based array)
   Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(arrB()) 'the zero after each byte does not matter when summing...
End Sub
```

The next version places the string in a byte array, but each character byte is followed by a zero:

```
Sub playWithBytesBis()
   Dim strMyString As String, arrB() As Byte
   strMyString = "ab9cd": arrB() = strMyString 'create a byte array, but each string byte is followed a zero element
   Debug.Print UBound(arrB())  'it returns 9 (10 elements in a zero based array)
   Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(arrB())
End Sub
```